# I want to know how to execute this in $? in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Does $? value gets set to true all the time?  In the example below is it being set to TRUE because I wrote `silentlycontinue`. In this script I am managing error handling for a file to get contents from  a user input: script that tests if the file is busy wait 2 seconds before accessing it again as in:

```
$filecontent =  get-content $filename -ea silentlycontinue 
**while (-not $?)**  
{       
$filecontent = get-content $filename -ea silentlycontinue 
    start-sleep: -sec 2     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> $?  Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>   TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

It's value has nothing to do with the ErrorActionPreference setting :

```
PS>$ErrorActionPreference="continue"
PS>gc afile.txt                                                                                                             
gc : Impossible de trouver le chemin d'accès « C:\Users\u1\afile.txt », car il n'existe pas.                       
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1                                                                                                    
+ gc afile.txt                                                                                                              
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                  

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\u1\afile.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand                                  

PS>$? 
False 
PS>$ErrorActionPreference="silentlycontinue" 
PS>gc afile.txt  #no error message displayed
PS>$?   
False
```

A better way to handle this is to make all errors terminating ones by setting $ErrorActionPreference to "stop" and use a try catch statement

```
function openFile{
    try{
    $file=[System.io.File]::Open('c:\windows\windowsupdate.log', 'Open', 'Read', 'None') 
    }
    catch{
        write-host "File is locked"
        start-sleep 2
        openFile
    }
    finaly{
        return $file
    }
}

$ErrorActionPreference="stop"  
$file=openFile
```